# Test abstract class calls parent method in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mockito, abstract-class

I'm currently refactoring features and I ended up with this abstractions

I have this classes

```py
class AbstractClassA(SomeOtherAbstractClass):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_abstract_method(self):
        pass

    def my_method(self)):
       service.some_method

class AbstractClassB(AbstractClassA):
    @abstractmethod
    def another_abstract_method(self):
        pass

    def some_abstract_method(self): 
        some_implementation

    def my_method(self):
        super().my_method()
        do_any_other_stuff
```

And I need to test if the `AbstractClassB.my_method` calls `super().my_method()`.

I've tried to test this by creating some `ImplementationClass` that inherits from `AbstractClassB` and then mocking the `AbstractClassA.my_method` and checking if it was called but it didn't work...

```py
class AbstractClassBImplementation(AbstractClassB):
    def some_abstract_method(self):
        calls_service()


class TestAbstractClassB(TestCase):
    @patch('module.submodule.AbstractClassA.my_method')
    def test_class_b_calls_class_a_my_method(self, my_method_mock):
        instance = AbstractClassBImplementation()

        instance.my_method()

        self.assertTrue(my_method_mock.called)
```

Someone know how to test this?

Comment: Is there a side-effect of `AbstractClassA.my_method` that you can observe? If so, you could see that that observable occurs when you call `AbstractClassB.my_method`.

Comment: Yes! But the problem is that `unitttest` is telling me that the `AbstractClassA.my_method` was never called :(

Comment: This should work, even if instanciating `AbstractClassB`. You are in Python 3, right?

Comment: Can you please turn your example in a truly running one, because the problem is not apparent from the piece of code you have shown.